# Weierstrass invariant on a particular lattice

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-functions

Consider the function

\begin{eqnarray*}
\wp(z)=\frac{1}{z^2}+\sum_{a\in \Lambda^*}\left( \frac{1}{(z-a)^2}-\frac{1}{a^2}\right)
\end{eqnarray*}

where $\Lambda = \mathbb{Z}\bigoplus\omega\mathbb{Z} $ and $\omega$ is the third root of unity in the upper half plane.

I already know what the zeros of $\wp$ are, namely $\frac{\omega}{\omega - 1}$ and $\frac{\omega}{1-\omega}$ .  I need to prove that   $g_2(\omega)=60\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\frac{1}{\lambda^4}=0$
however it's not quite clear how to proceed, any help is gladly appreciated.

Comment: Same as your previous question, use that $\omega$ is an automorphism of the lattice https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4349633/zeros-of-the-weierstrass-p-function-in-special-cases/4349680?noredirect=1#comment9077723_4349680

Comment: @reuns Can I use the fact that the term z^2 in the series expansion of $\wp(z)$ is $3G_2z^2$ hence by the formula $\wp(\omega z)=\omega \wp(z)$ deduce that $\omega^2 z^2G_2=\omega z^2G_2$ and so $G_2=0$ ? I feel like it's a blunder but that's all I got

Comment: You can. But you can also just replace $\lambda$ by $\omega \lambda$ in your series. And it is $g_2$ or $G_4$ or $E_4$ or $c_4$, not $G_2$.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the hint of reuns, we know that from the identity $\omega^2+\omega+1=0$ we can deduce $\omega\Lambda=\Lambda$ , then

$$g_2(\omega)=g_2(\Lambda)=g_2(\omega\Lambda)=60\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda-0}\frac{1}{(\omega\lambda)^4}=60\omega^2\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda-0}\frac{1}{\lambda^4}=\omega^2g_2(\omega)$$

From this it clearly follows $g_2(\omega)=0$